# multiple divs hide show jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Maybe this is not possible, however, i have like 50 unique divs like this:

```
<div id="nyc_data">
<a href="#nyc_pics" class="hidden">nyc</a>
</div>

<div id="la_data">
<a href="#la_pics" class="hidden">la</a>
</div>

<div id="san_data">
<a href="#san_pics" class="hidden">san</a>
</div>
```

etc....

below is my jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
  var url=document.URL.split('#')[1];
  url=url.toLowerCase();
  if (url == "nyc_pics")
  {
    jQuery("#nyc_data").show();
    jQuery("#la_data, #san_data").hide();
  }

  if (url == "la_pics")
  {
    jQuery("#la_data").show();
    jQuery("#nyc_data, #san_data").hide();
  }

  if()
  {
  }
  etc....
 }
```

When this was 2 it was okay to write it out, but i can't possibly write a long jquery 50 times for each city or so. is there an efficient way to have a simple smaller jquery code?

Comment: jQuery(div[id$="_data"]).show() should work as it selects ever div with the id ending in "_data".

Comment: @KevinHufnagl Add that as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all the divs first, with jQuery selector id ending with '_data' as `[id$='_data']` and hide them all. This will hide your desired div as well.

Now get the desired div id from url, find it with jQuery and show.

If your uri is `mySite.com/myPage#nyc_pics` then `var urlHash = document.URL.split('#')[1]` will get "nyc_pics". After `toLowercase().replace("pics", "data")` this will be "nyc_data". Now,  `jQuery("#" + divToSHow)` will be `$("#nyc_data")`, which will match your div. Then you can show that single div with .show()

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    var urlHash = document.URL.split('#')[1];
    var divToSHow = urlHash .toLowerCase().replace("pics", "data");
    jQuery("div[id$='_data']").hide();
    jQuery("#" + divToSHow).show();
});
```

Comment: i understand the _data, however, how do you distinguish the urls? it also hides all the divs. when i click on la_pics i get blank.

Comment: @Menew Ah, my bad. Missed the string.replace bit. Updated the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this CSS selector:

```
jQuery('div[id$="_data"]').show();
```

In your example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    var url=document.URL.split('#')[1];
    url=url.toLowerCase();
    var currentId = '#' + url.split('_')[0] + "_data";
    jQuery('div[id$="_data"]').hide();
    jQuery(currentId).show();
}
```

Comment: i tried this and it hides all my divs when i click on a url.

Comment: @Menew Try this jQuery('div[id$="_data"]:not(currentId)').hide(); instead, and check if the currentId is the correct Id of the div you want to show, because I haven't tested the code.

Answer (score -1):

It would be much easier/cleaner/faster if you just used jQuery to toggle a class on a parent element and let CSS do the work. Something like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $('#all-the-things-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('#my-parent-div').toggleClass('show-things');
  });
};
```

```css
#my-parent-div > div {
  display: none;
}

#my-parent-div.show-things > div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="all-the-things-btn">Toggle all the things!</a>

<div id="my-parent-div" class="show-things">
  <div id="1">stuff</div>
  <div id="2">more stuff</div>
  <div id="3">even more stuff</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using a fancy box with cities so the first answer works perfectly. thanks though

Comment: I know it works. It's just not a great idea to lean to heavily on javascript when you dont need to. If you were going to hide/show a large amount of divs the CSS approach would work instantly on all and relatively faster than having jQuery iterate through all of them by brute force.